# Asp.net MVC: Unable to cast object of type 'Models.RegisterViewModel' to type 'Models.ApplicationUser'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently working on a ASP.NET application, and decided to make a custom validation. I added "Name" to my RegisterViewModel and ApplicationUser models, so that they would have a name, and want to verify that is unique. I made a class called UniqueName and set it as a validation property. The problem is with the casting of validationContext.ObjectInstance. When I cast it to ApplicationUser I get

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Starset.Models.RegisterViewModel' to type 'Starset.Models.ApplicationUser'.
```

when I try to register. When I cast it to RegisterViewModel I get

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Starset.Models.ApplicationUser' to type 'Starset.Models.RegisterViewModel'.
```

I tried using AutoMapper to map the two, but it didn't work. Why does it say my user object is of type RegisterViewModel, then that it is of type ApplicationUser? Which one?

```
public class UniqueName: ValidationAttribute
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public UniqueName()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var allUsers = _context.Users.ToList();
            var user = (RegisterViewModel) (validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            foreach(var existingUser in allUsers)
            {
                if(existingUser.Name == user.Name)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Username Taken");
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UniqueName]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [UniqueName]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Please help me finish my custom validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
 var userName = value.ToString();
  var userNameExist = _context.Users.Any(u=>u.Name==userName);
if(userNameExist) return new ValidationResult("Username Taken");
 return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped.